# How to refer another file in the same python package?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have the following file structure

```
myproject
|
+--mypackage
|  |
|  +--__init__.py
|  +--file1.py
|  +--file2.py
|
+--somescript1.py
+--somescript2.py
```

I can import `somescript1` from `somescript2` with

```
import somescript1
```

or

```
from somescript1 import *
```

and I will by able to use symbols from `somescript1`.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for `file2`. How to import `file1` from `file2`?

```
import file1
```

complains

```
No module named data.
```

**UPDATE**

It was PyCharm false syntax checking message.

Comment: error doesn't seem to be thrown by `import file1`, are you importing something else in file1 ?

Comment: Post your file1.py there seems to be an error in that file

Comment: Wow, sorry you are right people it was PyCharm false message....

Comment: Either way, when packing data as modules you want to keep your paths relative so in your `file2.py`:  `from . import file1`  or `from .file1 import *`

Comment: Also, it is preferential to do `import file` instead of `from file import *`